# Sending message to specific group of clients in socketio

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

What's the best way to send a message via socket io to a group of users, for example only those in a specific chat room instead of all users?

I am aware of [Sending data only to chosen users using Socket.io-node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943573/sending-data-only-to-chosen-users-using-socket-io-node) but socketio version .7 was released recently and seems like there might be a more elegant way with the new api using either get/set or namespacing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you should look up room concept:

> ### Rooms
>
> Sometimes you want to put certain sockets in the same room, so that it's easy to broadcast to all of them together.
>
> Think of this as built-in channels for sockets. Sockets join and leave rooms in each socket.
>
> Server side:
>
> ```
> var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
>
> io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
>   socket.join('justin bieber fans');
>   socket.broadcast.to('justin bieber fans').emit('new fan');
>   io.sockets.in('rammstein fans').emit('new non-fan');
> });
> ```

Comment: In this example, everyone would be a member of the `justin bieber fans` room. Suppose on connection the client sent a group ID they were a member of, could one simple create a room, and emit to a room using a variable, like so ` `group${groupID}` ` ?