# how can i send and receive messages separately with nodejs ws

Tags: node.js, ws

i got this code example from npm that im using for one of my projects :

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path');

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('something');
});

ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

my issue:
after socket is open im sending command message with ws.send('{command:123}')
what im expecting is to get the message direct for this command
and then i want to send another command and get the message from that new command but separately .

at the moment when im sending command and there is more then one it display only one message but with both of the command responses.
so what im trying to accomplish is:

send command 
receive message
do something with that message
send another command 
do something with the new message

i hope that i explained well.
thanks

Comment: Maybe it should helper you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445883/node-websocket-server-possible-to-have-multiple-separate-broadcasts-for-a-si

Comment: no it dosent , im not working on chat or working with users, im working as a client in front of web socket , i need to send command and get the response immediately and use it, then i want to send other command and many more and use each response and not wait for one response in total. thanks